# Printing colored message in debugging console in flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am asking if there any way to print colored messages in debugging console not only the default color. It help a lot in the debugging process.

If it doesn't depend on any packages it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flutter developer logs for that.

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
```

And you can log anywhere in your code.

```
 developer.log('log me', name: 'my.app.category');
 developer.log('log me 1', name: 'my.other.category');
 developer.log('log me 2', name: 'my.other.category');
```

For more details see. https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#logging

Comment: Does this answer the question? Where are the colors?

Comment: not as aspected.

Answer (score -6):

try this one

```
pip install colored
```

how I did find it ?

```
pypi color print
```

on google

Comment: I am asking about flutter not python @Bahae. thanks for your efforts.